# Installing third party plugin on QGIS with Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, installation

I have downloaded a zip file containing a third party plug-in for QGIS3.6 (named AVHYAS, downloaded from https://vedas.sac.gov.in/en/download.html). The plug-in was installed via Plugins -> Manage and install plug-ins -> Install from ZIP. However, there is an error when trying to run the plug-in, because I can't seem to find how to properly install the python packages/modules. I got the following info from the manual, but I guess it is for Windows.

How can this procedure be carried out on a Mac?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently AVHYAS has no support for MAC and Linux users. The plugin has been tested for Windows only as of now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).